# Binding doesn't work in MVVM in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am new in the development of WP8. I have been following a online course for a couple of weeks and the second task of the course was to develop a app to show the weather, some news and photos related to the city.
So far, I have develop the app following the MVVM pattern using the Panorama control as the conteiner for the differents contents I need to show. 
To no longer this, the problem I facing is at the moment to display the xml data that is retrieve from the webservices.

**The XAML is:**

```
<phone:panorama x:Name="myPanorama"
            DataContext = {Binding Source="WeatherViewModel"}>
   <PanoramaItem header="MyWeather">
      <Textblock x:name="txtCity"
       Text = {Binding Weather.City}
      </Textblock>       
   </PanoramaItem>
   <panoramaItem header="Config">
      <Text x:Name="txtGetCity"/>
      <Button x:Name="btnGetCity"
              Command={Binding GetWeatherCommand}/>
   </panoramaItem>
</phone:panorama>
```

**My ViewModel:**

```
public class WeaterViewModel : NotificationEnableObject
{
   private Weather _currentWeather;        
   public Weather GetCurrentWeather
   {
        get
        {
            if (_currentWeather == null)
                _currentWeather = new Weather();

            return _currentWeather;
        }
        set { _currentWeather = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("GetCurrentWeather"); 
        }
 }

//Constructor        ServiceModel serviceModel = new ServiceModel();
 public WeatherViewModel()
 {
        serviceModel.GetWeatherCompleted += (s, a) =>
        {
            _currentWeather = new Clima();
            _currentWeather.City= a.Results[0].City;
            _currentWeather.tempC = a.Results[0].tempC;
        };

        getWeatherCommand = new ActionCommand(null);
  }

   ActionCommand getWeatherCommand;  // ActionCommand derivied from ICommand      
   public ActionCommand GetWeatherCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (getWeatherCommand!= null)
            {
                getWeatherCommand = new ActionCommand(() =>
                    {
                        //Call the Service who retrieved the data
                    });
            }

            return getWeatherCommand;
        }
    }

}
```

The Weather specified is a public class which contain the City property. I have tried using an IObservableCollention as well howerver, the result is the same :-(

As you can see in the panorama control I have 2 sections. The one where I write the city I wanna see and the section where I show the information I get from the web services.

Any clue, or help would be very appreciate

Regards!

Comment: With this little code it is only possible to speculate on what is going wrong. Could you add the relevant pieces of the WeatherViewModel class (maybe also the weather class) and where the data is loaded?

Comment: Hi Stefan Wexel. I've modified the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think that is an easy fix.
You're setting `GetCurrentWeather` this way:

```
_currentWeather = new Clima();
_currentWeather.City= a.Results[0].City;
_currentWeather.tempC = a.Results[0].tempC;
```

This is not firing the `PropertyChanged` event. Change it to:

```
GetCurrentWeather= new Clima();
GetCurrentWeather.City= a.Results[0].City;
GetCurrentWeather.tempC = a.Results[0].tempC;
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: Hi Stefan. I haven't answer you back 'cause I wasn't close to my laptop.I've tested your suggestion and it works OK. Now, I see what was the problem. Thanks so much for your help.